# Meaning of “outrage”

Tags: vocabulary

The pay cuts proposed by the management caused an (outrage) among the workers.
Choose the word that means the same as the word in parentheses
a) anger
B) shame
C) disappointment

I can say the answer is option a but it may be option c since it is fromcthe management to the workers so if the workers were anger it is not a problem for the manager.

Comment: We [***don't usually include the article***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=caused+outrage%2Ccaused+an+outrage&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccaused%20outrage%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccaused%20an%20outrage%3B%2Cc0) when saying that ***something caused outrage.***

Answer (score 1):

The sentence says the workers are angry. They may also be disappointed, but that's not what the sentence says.

Whether or not that anger is a problem for management is not addressed here.

> out·rage
> /ˈoutˌrāj/
> noun: **outrage**
> an extremely strong reaction of anger, shock, or indignation.
> "her voice trembled with outrage"

From a [google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=outrage+meaning).